# nodejs/express express.createserver is not a function

Tags: node.js, express

I am quite new to node.js I am trying to use nodemailer to send an email and I am currently getting a type error on the console.

//error//
[0] TypeError: express.createServer is not a function
[0]     at app.post (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/server.js:33:17)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at next (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
[0]     at Route.dispatch (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
[0]     at /Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
[0]     at Function.process_params (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
[0]     at next (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
[0]     at urlencodedParser (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:82:7)
[0]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/thomashunt/Desktop/react_express_starter/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)

// end of error

here is the code to my server.js file:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 5000
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
  })
)

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  console.log(
    'Hello from .get /home',
    req.body.generalDetails,
    req.body.firstName,
    req.body.mName
  )
})

app.post('/home', (req, res) => {


  var express = require('express'),
  nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

  app = express.createServer();

  app.use(express.bodyParser());

  app.post('/formProcess', function (req, res) {
      var data=req.body;

      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
         service: "Gmail",
         auth: {
         user: "thomas.hunt@careertrackers.org.au",
         pass: "pass"
         }});

     smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
     from: "email",
     to: "thomas.hunt@careertrackers.org.au", // receiver
     subject: "Emailing with nodemailer", // subject
     text:req.body.generalDetails,
     html: "here your data goes"// body (var data which we've declared)
      }, function(error, response){  //callback
           if(error){
             console.log(error);
          }else{
             console.log("Message sent: " + res.message);
         }

     smtpTransport.close();
      }); });

  let data = [{
    //page one data
    generalDetails: req.body.generalDetails,
    fName: req.body.fName,
    mName: req.body.mName,
    lName: req.body.lName,
    email: req.body.email,
   }];

   res.json(data);

 }

);

app.listen(port, () => `Server running on port ${port}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused with `http` modules. Replace your

```
app = express.createServer();
```

with

```
app = express();
```

If you want to use `createServer`, you should do the following

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
var app = express();

... your route config

var server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Express is running on port 3000')
})
```